# Android MapView without location labels

Tags: android

I want to use MapView control in satellite view mode but i don't want to show location labels on it i.e, I want blank satellite view of map in which name of places are not shown.I have searched web a lot but couldn't find a way out.How can I achieve this.Thanks in advance...

Comment: prashant its display hybrid view and you cant remove labels......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images provided to the MapView from Google have that data built into it, it#s not an overlay and there is no option to get it without. So you can't.